# Android dynamic linking. Thinking about forced updates

Tags: android

I was wondering if it's even possible. Let's say I separated my app into "Library loader" and "Library" where library piece can be downloaded by "Library loader" from my server.

This way I don't need to rely on users to install updates to my app.

I understand it's probably not possible, but stillw wonder what you all know :)

This is internal business app and updates always pain. I do throw notifications to user, etc and there is still problem forcing user to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe this is possible. Swype / the Swype Installer work this way.  You might investigate it.

From what I remember:

You install the Swype Installer from an APK, then run it.

The installer downloads the Swype APK, and chaperones you through the system dialogs to install and enable Swype.

When Swype decides your beta key has expired, or whatever, it disables itself and then you use the installer to update.

This isn't dynamic linking at all though but it is a system to support forced updates.

**Update:**

**Blog post from Google talks about dynamic class loading here:**

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it is not going to help. I give user Notification which they can click and go directly to Market and Update. So, if I can't do it silently - there is no difference..

Comment: Hmm, this message on the Android developers google group is interesting to this question:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5f71b5f1cabd5d71#

It's talking about this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi

Comment: @katit - the difference is that by disabling the old version, you force them to upgrade if they want to keep using the app.  FYI many users will **hate** this on principle.

Comment: Users will hate it, it takes 10 seconds to upgrade. Our main users inside office and they pay for application. Mobile users just need to use it..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, and if you have root access, certainly, although what I'm thinking of would require the NDK.  When you load data with the NDK, it is done dynamically.  So if you replace that library, it would obviously update the functionality.

However, I do see many possible issues with this.  The largest of which is I'm not sure if you have write access to where your library is stored (once the app is installed anyway).  But I'm not sure of this.  The folder is /data/data/(package name)/lib.  I do know you have some limited access to the parent of that folder though (as that's where your database is stored).

Comment: Without root you do no have write access to where a packaged NDK library is placed during installation, but you aren't constrained to only loading libraries from that location - you can put them in the location found by Context.getDir() or Context.getFilesDir() and then load them using full path and .so file name using System.load() instead of System.loadLibrary().